# Undefined method in list view when using belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some weird reason, associations in my list view is not working consistently. 
In my models I have:

```
Class Restaurant  < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many  :menus

Class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
Belongs_to  :restaurant
```

In my controller I have:

```
def list
    @menus = Menu.order("menus.id ASC")
end
```

In my view I have:

```
<% = menus.each do |menu| %>
    <h4><%= menu.restaurant.name %></h4>
<% end %>
```

I am getting undefined method “name” .  name is a column in the restaurant table.

However, it works in my show view when I use `< %= @menu.restaurant.name % >` with no problem.

I am using rails 3.2.9 and ruby  1.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one of your `@menus` probably doesn't have its associated `restaurant`.

Try typing  in your console `Menu.includes(:restaurant).each{|m| puts m.id unless m.restaurant}` to see what `menu` record(s) cause this problem.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As Marek Lipka said, you have Menu that are not linked to restaurant.

So reference to `menu.restaurant` is nil.

If it is intended to have menu without restaurant, you can bypass Nil reference in your view :

```
<%= menu.restaurant.try(:name) %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try